# Python import RandomForestClassifier のエラー

Tags: python, python3

`from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier` というコードを実行すると
以下のエラーが出ます。

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

様々なモジュールをインストールしましたが、エラーが消えません。
どうしたらRandomForestClassifierを正常に使えるでしょうか？
Visual Studio Codeを使っており MacBook Pro です。
私自身sklearn等の知識は全くありません。

このコードは以下のページを引用してきた物です。

[子供にもわかるAIじゃんけんプログラム](https://ameblo.jp/maurundog/entry-12672740180.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pipを使っているのであれば`pip install -U scikit-learn`でインストールしてはどうでしょうか？
詳しくはドキュメント[Installing scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)をご覧ください。

【追記】

> 私が使ってる環境はVisual Code Studio を使っているのにcondaでダウンロードをした記憶があるのと実行したところユーザー/ユーザー名/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/bin/python:と出ました。関係があるのでしょうか？ –

上記によると、pyenv + Anaconda でpython3の環境構築をされたということでしょうか？

condaとpipは同一環境で併用してはいけないとされています。モジュールをimportできないのはそれが原因かもしれません。詳細は[Conda と Pip](https://www.python.jp/install/anaconda/pip_and_conda.html)をご確認ください。

Anacondaを削除してもう一度インストールするのが良いかと思います。
[Anaconda3をmacOSから完全にアンインストールする方法](https://analytics-note.xyz/mac/pyenv-uninstall-versions/)などが参考になるかもしれません。（私はpyenv使用していないため検証はしてません）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。実行してみたところRequirement already satisfiedと出たので恐らくもうインストールされていたようですが、エラーは未だ出続けています。　　　　どうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: もしかしてM1macでしょうか？ またscikit-learn 1.1.1でしょうか？

Comment: 「visual studioを使っており」とのことですが、ターミナルで実行された場合にも「ModuleNotFoundError」が出ますか？

Comment: もう1点確認ですが、最新のVisual Studio for MacではPythonはサポートされていないようです。https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ja/vs/mac/　過去のバージョンではサポートされていたのでしょうか？バージョンについても追記されるとより良い回答がつくかもしれません。

Comment: 回答遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。visual sudio と記入していましたが正しくはVisual sudio code です。ターミナルの方ではまだ実行しておりません。M1macではありません。`pip show scikit-learn`を実行したところバージョン0.24.2と出ました。

Comment: pythonの方で実行してみてもエラーが出ました。

Comment: 「pythonの方で実行してみてもエラーが出ました。 」のエラーは「ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'」ですか？ そうであればscikit-learnをインストールしたpython環境とコードを実行しているpython環境が異なる可能性が考えられます。「!python -V」で表示されるpythonはscikit-learnをインストールしたpythonと同じですか？（仮想環境を利用されている場合は同じ仮想環境ですか？）

Comment: 私が使ってる環境はVisual Code Studio を使っているのにcondaでダウンロードをした記憶があるのと実行したところユーザー/ユーザー名/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/bin/python:と出ました。関係があるのでしょうか？

Comment: アナコンダを入れたところ解決しました。

Comment: 長いこと付き合ってくださりありがとうございます。